# Wordpress process API request in the background

Tags: wordpress, api

I have a few API endpoints on my WordPress page. The problem is, that the response-time takes about (6 – 30 seconds – depends on what is to do).

When a client sends a request to my API he has to wait for 6 – 30 seconds for a response and that is the problem.

I read about background dispatch – how does this work with WordPress? The only thing the API does is insert, delete or update posts.

At the moment the API does the following:

1. Validate data
2. Check if the client_id exists and the client_secret matches
3. Check if the post already exists -> if yes update -> if no create
4. Update / Create post
5. (optional) Upload images with media_sideload_image()
   5/6. Update custom fields -> update_field()

   ```
           if (have_rows("api_users", "options")) {
               while (have_rows("api_users", "options")) {
                   the_row();

                   if (get_sub_field("api_user_client_id") == $client_id) {
                       $flag = true;
                   }
               }
           }

           if (!$flag) {
               wp_send_json_error(array("message" => "Wrong ClientID"));
           }

           return false;
       }

       public function rest_create_xxx($request) {
           // check if clientID is correct
           $this->checkIfClientIsAllowed($request->get_param("client_id"));

           // validate params
           $params = $request->get_params();
           $validator = $this->validation->make($params, array(
               // my validation rules
           ));

           if ($validator->fails()) {
                wp_send_json_error(array("message" => "validation failed");
           }

           // check if parent post exist
           $result = self::findPostByInternId("yyy", $request->get_param("client_id"), $request->get_param("parent"));
           $parent_post = 0;

           if ($result->have_posts() && $result->post_count == 1) {
               $parent_post = $result->posts[0];
           } else {
               wp_send_json_error(array("message" => "parent post not found"));
           }

           // check if xxx with that id already exists (if yes update, if no insert)
           $result = self::findPostByInternId("xxx", $request->get_param("client_id"), $request->get_param("intern_id"));
           $post = null;

           if ($result->have_posts() && $result->post_count == 1) {
               // post already exist - so update it
               $post = wp_update_post(array(
                   "ID" => $result->posts[0]->ID,
                   "post_title" => $request->get_param("title"),
                   "post_type" => "xxx",
                   "post_parent" => $parent_post->ID,
                   "post_status" => "publish"
               ));
           } else {
               // post not found - so insert it
               $post = wp_insert_post(array(
                   "post_title" => $request->get_param("title"),
                   "post_type" => "xxx",
                   "post_parent" => $parent_post->ID,
                   "post_status" => "publish"
               ));
           }

           // update some acf fields
           update_field("a", $request->get_param("a"), $post);
           update_field("b", $request->get_param("b"), $post);
           update_field("c", $request->get_param("c"), $post);

           wp_send_json_success();
       }
   ?>
   ```

Comment: Please provide code sample and how it's being triggered.

Comment: I added the code